# Joomla Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, hardening, centos, joomla

I installed Joomla 3 to `/var/www/html` directory in Cent OS 6 server. Currently `/var/www/html` is owned by `apache:apache`.

What is the recommended permissions for Joomla installation on Linux in production environment. Who should own what with which permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what finally used as a bash file.

```
#/bin/bash
chown -R root:root /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
PLACES='
administrator/components
administrator/modules
administrator/templates
cache
components
images
images/banners
images/articles
language
media
modules
templates
'
for i in $PLACES; do chown -R apache:apache $i; done


find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

Comment: dont need to if your run with suphp: http://www.suphp.org/Home.html

Comment: I wouldn't give a web server write access to a file or folder if it does not need it.